# Consequences of $X X^T = Y Y^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

I think this should imply that $Y = X U$ where $X$ is a unitary matrix. In the case where one of the matrices is invertible, this is immediate because, multiplying on the left by $X^{-1}$ and the right by $X^{-T}$, 
$$ I = X^{-1} Y Y^T X^{-T},$$ which implies that $X^{-1} Y$ is unitary as needed. But I'm not sure how to prove this when $X$ is not invertible.

Comment: What are you assuming about the dimensions of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Lets say they are both $n \times r$, where $r$ is the rank of $X X^T=Y Y^T$. Actually, I think we can, without loss of generality, assume they are both $n \times n$. First, we can always pad them with zero columns to make them $n \times n$. If we can obtain the conclusion $Y = X U$ for a unitary $U$ in this (padded) setting, then we can further argue that only the top $r \times r$ submatrix of $U$ is nonzero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use the word *isometry* rather than *unitary* because *isometry* applies to both real and complex inner product spaces.

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are linear operators on a finite-dimensional inner product space such that $XX^* = YY^*$. By the Polar Decomposition (as applied to $X^*$ and $Y^*$; see Theorem 7.45 in *Linear Algebra Done Right*, third edition), there exist isometries $A$ and $B$ such that
$$
X = \sqrt{XX^*} A \quad \text{ and } Y = \sqrt{YY^*} B.
$$
Thus $\sqrt{XX^*} = X  A^{-1}$ and hence
$$
Y = \sqrt{XX^*} B = X  A^{-1} B.
$$
Let $U = A^{-1}B$. Then $U$ is an isometry and $Y = XU$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks for a fine answer and an awesome book!